# How to get html source code after javascript transformation?

Tags: php, javascript, html, curl

for a project at school I am trying to make a website that can show your grades in a prettier way than it's being done now.
I have been able to log in to the site using cURL and now I want to get the grades in a string so I can edit it with PHP. 
The only problem is that cURL gets the html source code when it hasn't been edited by the javascript that gets the grades.

So basically I want the code that you get when you open firebug or inspector in a string so I can edit it with php.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? I have seen several posts that say that you have to wait till the page has loaded, but I have no clue on how to make my site wait for another third-party site to be loaded.

The code that I am waiting to be executed and of which I want the result is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var widgetWrapper = $("#objectWrapper325");
    if (widgetWrapper[0].timer !== undefined) {
        clearTimeout( jQuery('#objectWrapper325')[0].timer );
    }
    widgetWrapper[0].timer = setTimeout( function() {
        if (widgetWrapper[0].xhr !== undefined) {
            widgetWrapper[0].xhr.abort();
        }
        widgetWrapper[0].xhr = jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "",
            data: {
                "wis_ajax": 1,
                "ajax_object": 325,
                'llnr': '105629'
            },
            success: function(d) {
                var goodWidth = widgetWrapper.width();
                widgetWrapper.html(d);
                /* update width, needed for bug with standard template */
                $("#objectWrapper325 .result__overview").css('width',goodWidth-$("#objectWrapper325         .result__subjectlabels").width());
            }
        });
    }, 500+(Math.random()*1000));
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot get content generating in javascript from PHP - this is why it called server side and client side - server side can take only what the server serves and client side handling the client data - what you can do is sniff that page and call to the page that the ajax js code is calling - and then get the response and process it in the server

Comment: If I understand correctly, The process is opposite of what you want to do.  The PHP executes before anything client-side.  You would have to pull the information on another page and use something like an ajax call to collect the information and display it.  Or pull the information from one side, then place it in a database, then push it to the page you want to view it on.

Comment: This is where something like phantomjs or zombiejs is useful

Comment: You won't be able to edit it with PHP because PHP is executed in the server (away from your computer) and HTML/Javascript is nothing but code until it reaches your browser (at this time PHP has already resolved and there is no way you can execute it)

Comment: Trying to intercept your grades so your parents don't bust you is poor form.

Comment: Do you control the PHP that provides the AJAX update? If so, do the editing there in PHP. If you don't mind doing the transformation in JavaScript, modify `d` in your `success` function.

Comment: @Adidi and ntgCleaner: You say that I should use the same ajax function like above, only that I should change the URL it is sending to right? I have tried to do that, but still it doesn't come up with results.

Comment: @David: Haha, I am not trying to intercept my grades, I am just trying to display them. No need to worry there ;)

Comment: @halfer: no, I unfortunately do not control the PHP that provides this script. Thanks to all of you for replying.

Answer (score 6):

First you have to understand a subtle but very important difference between using cURL to get a webpage, and using your browser visiting that same page.

#### 1. Loading a page with a browser

When you enter the address on the location bar, the browser converts the url into an ip address  . Then  it tries to reach the **web server** with that address asking for a web page. From now on the browser will only speak **HTTP** with the web server. HTTP is a protocol made for carrying documents over network. The browser is actually asking for an html document (A bunch of text) from the web server. The web server answers by sending the web page to the browser. If the web page is a static page, the web server is just picking an html file and sending it over network. If it's a dynamic page, the web server use some high level code (like php) to generate to the web page then send it over.

Once the web page has been downloaded, the browser will then parse the page and interprets the html inside which produces the actual web page on the browser. During the parsing process, when the browser finds `script` tags it will interpret their content as javascript, which is a language used in browser to manipulate the look of the web page and do stuff inside the browser.

Remember, the web server only sent a web page containing html content  he has no clue of what's javascript.

So when you load a web page on a browser the javascript is ONLY interpreted once it is downloaded on the browser.

### 2. What is cURL

If you take a look at curl man page, you'll learn that curl is a tool to transfer data from/to servers which can speak some supported protocols and HTTP is one of them. 
When you download a page with curl, it will try to **download** the page the same way your browser does it but will not parse or interpret anything. cURL does not understand javascript or html, all it knows about is how to speak to web servers.

#### 3. Solution

So what you need in your case is to download the page like cURL does it and also somehow make the javascript to be interpreted as if it was inside a browser.

If you had follwed me up to here then you're ready to take a look at [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/index.html).

Comment: Ok I understand everything you said, that cURL doesn't have a java interpreter as it is not a browser. I have read some posts which mentioned phantomJS and other related utilities, but I have no idea on how to use them. If I download the library is there just a function like interpret.javascript or something that makes the javascirpt work?

Comment: Also, I am not the only one that should be able to see my grades. Are PhantomJs and CasperJS installed on your computer, or is it just a repository that you can include in a directory on your server?

Comment: Javascript.. not java.  They are two different languages.