# Get result of HTML and JavaScript code in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to get the result of shown JavaScript and HTML code. For example, when we write `document.write("Hello")`, `return "Hello"`.
Look at this code:

```
$html_code = <<<EOL

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Hello World</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script>
                document.write("Hello World");
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>

EOL;

$result = getResult($html_code);

echo $result;
```

I want to get this result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can Directly write html into php file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775303/how-to-get-html-source-code-after-javascript-transformation

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to print the raw html, or are you trying to display the result of the rendered html?

Comment: I need something like HtmlUnit (that is for Java) for PHP.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what exactly you want and what you want to use it for. I don't understand your question!

Comment: It still is unclear what you want to do. Are you scraping HTML pages and want the contents after Javascript code has been executed. Otherwise I can not see the motivation to do this.

Comment: I need a JavaScript simulator that can parse it.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to get the result of a HTML page with embedded Javascript code on the server side, in the same script that generates this HTML and Javascript code.

**You can not!**

### The reason

- The PHP script runs on the server side.
- The HTML code (with the embedded Javascript code) has to be interpreted by a browser on the client side.
- The browser would execute the Javascript code. And only then the Javascript code (**document.write("Hello World");**) would create the "Hello world" HTML text. And only then the HTML text would look like you are expecting.

In brief: you expect a result on the server side which had to be produced on the client side before.

In your example you could directly have the PHP script generate the "Hello world" text - no need for Javascript.