# Execute JS in server side with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm explaining. example.com has the below source code (the snippets).

There is possible to use `$example = file_get_contents('http://example.com');` and get table already generated ?

I want that `$example` has the code source below after executed in client side.

Sorry if I've not been clear. I can explain more detail in the commentary.

```js
var table = document.createElement('table');   
    table.setAttribute('class', 'table');
      for(let i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
            for(let j = 0; j <= 5; j++){
              let td = document.createElement('td');
                td.appendChild(
                document.createTextNode('Tr ' + i + ' td ' + j));
                //Add td to tr
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            //Add tr to the table
            table.appendChild(tr);
      }
      document.getElementById('app').appendChild(table);

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Table generated</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: No, PHP cannot execute JS.

Comment: Is `example.com` a file on the server?

Comment: No. example.com is a url. `http://example.com`

Comment: `file_get_contents` will return you the source code of the site. Not the HTML output. Perhaps you want to use `curl` instead.

Comment: That's what I want exactly. The code source. Finally, What I mean is could there be an API where I can submit this source code and the API will return the interpreted source code exactly as the browser does?

Comment: There is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) but it is apparently abandoned.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/q/15775303/296555